# Making clip feature optional in ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, modelbuilder

I want to make the clip feature an option, and also a model parameter so that the one who will use it will have the option to add it or skip it.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It will needed entered as a model entry before you run the model, but just add a binary-if statement before that tool, and make it a pre-condition to the clip tool.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can add boolean variable and set it as precondition to that clip tool. Boolean variable when you run model appears as a square which you can tick on or off.

Comment: But I don't want to make the clip tool a precondition, I want to make the variable that is going to be clipped a precondition